# 3 Buttons and I want the other 2 remain inactive when the 1 clicked is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function toggleSlideBox(x) {
        $("#"+x).slideToggle(300);

  }
```

Okay so I'm using this javscript feature on each of the buttons to creat a drop down that hold forms, text, etc. and when I click one (ex. the first) then when it drops, the other two buttons drop below it. And if i click the last, then the first two buttons stay on top.

2 things:
 I just want one button to be able to be active at a time.
 I would like all 3 buttons to remain on top

Here's the rest of the code for help:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleSlideBox('three');"><input name="#" type="button" id="#" value="Ask"></input></a>
<div id="three" style="background-color:#06A1F1; border:#999 1px solid; padding:12px; display:none; margin-top:8px;">
                <textarea name="#" cols="80px" rows="3" style="resize: none;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';">Content</textarea>
                <br />
                <input style="float:right; margin-right:80px;" type="button" value="Post!"></input>
                <br />
</div>
                <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleSlideBox('two');"><input name="#" type="button" id="#" value="Post!"></input></a>
<div id="two" style="background-color:#06A1F1; border:#999 1px solid; padding:12px; display:none; margin-top:8px;">
                <textarea name="#" cols="15px" rows="1" style="resize: none;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';">Title</textarea>
                <textarea name="#" cols="80px" rows="3" style="resize: none;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';">Content</textarea>
                <br />
                <input style="float:right; margin-right:80px;" type="button" value="Post!"></input>
                <br />
</div>
                <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleSlideBox('one');"><input name="#" type="button" id="#" value="Write!"></input></a>
<div id="one" style="background-color:#06A1F1; border:#999 1px solid; padding:12px; display:none; margin-top:8px;">
                <textarea name="#" cols="15px" rows="1" style="resize: none;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';">Title</textarea>
                <textarea name="#" cols="80px" rows="3" style="resize: none;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';">Content</textarea>
                <br />
                <input style="float:right; margin-right:80px;" type="button" value="Post!"></input>
                <br />
```

Comment: Try separating your JS from CSS from HTML. You'd probably get more people to help. Right now it's such a mess that few people will try to help, we're lazy...Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Re-ordering the elements can help:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleSlideBox('three');"><input name="#" type="button" id="#" value="Ask"></input></a>
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleSlideBox('two');"><input name="#" type="button" id="#" value="Post!"></input></a>
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleSlideBox('one');"><input name="#" type="button" id="#" value="Write!"></input></a>
<div id="three" style="background-color:#06A1F1; border:#999 1px solid; padding:12px; display:none; margin-top:8px;">
                <textarea name="#" cols="80px" rows="3" style="resize: none;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';">Content</textarea>
                <br />
                <input style="float:right; margin-right:80px;" type="button" value="Post!"></input>
                <br />
</div>
<div id="two" style="background-color:#06A1F1; border:#999 1px solid; padding:12px; display:none; margin-top:8px;">
                <textarea name="#" cols="15px" rows="1" style="resize: none;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';">Title</textarea>
                <textarea name="#" cols="80px" rows="3" style="resize: none;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';">Content</textarea>
                <br />
                <input style="float:right; margin-right:80px;" type="button" value="Post!"></input>
                <br />
</div>
<div id="one" style="background-color:#06A1F1; border:#999 1px solid; padding:12px; display:none; margin-top:8px;">
                <textarea name="#" cols="15px" rows="1" style="resize: none;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';">Title</textarea>
                <textarea name="#" cols="80px" rows="3" style="resize: none;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';">Content</textarea>
                <br />
                <input style="float:right; margin-right:80px;" type="button" value="Post!"></input>
                <br />
```

- Please try to keep the UI separate from the JS logic. May be you can put all the JS in a separate file.
- Keep the styling in a different CSS file. That will help you easily manipulate the UI without having to go through lines of mixed up HTML.

Comment: thanks for the help, that does keep them on top! I will also try and seperate out more, sometimes just adding a style seems easier :) thank you!

Comment: Yes, that will keep them on the top. Here is your code (re-ordered): http://jsfiddle.net/FWMun/